# Android Spinner - onItemSelected / setOnItemSelectedListener Update Issue

Tags: java, android

I have an issue which I just cannot get my head around. In my experience, code follows the sequence it is run in, but this does not appear to be the case in this instance.

I have two UI items, namely a spinner and an edittext field which are populated from a DB table in a function called from onCreate(). When the spinner is set (using setSelection) it kicks off the onItemSelected which sets the edittext value to a default value. After this, I then set the edittext field (using setText) to the value stored in the DB, but the new value does not appear.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
spinnerdresslength.setSelection(backuplengthoptionid);
edittextskirtshortestlength.setText(backupshortestlength);
```

The event handler looks like as follows (I have simplified it for the sake of ease):

```
spinnerdresslength.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
          edittextskirtshortestlength.setText("43");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });`
```

Now despite the edittextskirtshortestlength.setText(backupshortestlength) following the spinner setSelection, the edittext shows 43 instead of backupshortestlength.

Can you anybody assist with this as I am at my wits end?

Thanks,
NicVegas

Comment: please put your spinner adapter code here

Comment: replace edittextskirtshortestlength.setText(yourArray.get(arg2));

Comment: spinnerdresslength = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerdresslength); - thats the only other code i have in reference to it.

Comment: Can anybody assist?